# Where do these links in my generated PDF come from?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat

After converting a Word document to PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.9.3, I open the created PDF and want to highlight the hyperlinks in the document so that the user could see that there's something clickable.

In general, this works fine, but there's strange stuff in the TOC of the document (the TOC was created in Word):

[image: pdf screenshot]

See what I mean? I added a blue border around each hyperlink. But where do these hyperlinks after the chapter number come from? They point to the same place where also the chapter numbers point to.

Relevant PDF creation settings are:

- convert Word headings to hyperlinks
- convert Word styles to hyperlinks

De-selecting *convert Word styles to hyperlinks* doesn't change anything.

---

**EDIT:**
Obviously this is caused by my styles for the TOC, but I can not figure out, what it is...

---

**EDIT 2:**
After playing around with the formatting of my TOC styles, I figured out that it only happens, when my selected font size of a style is smaller than 12pt. Maybe this helps anyone to provide me an answer. I refuse to believe that changing the font size of the TOC entries results in different hyperlinks...

---

**EDIT 3:**
I had a look on the styles used in the resulting TOC:[image: toc]

Green marks text formatted as `hyperlink`, red marks text being formatted as `toc-style-1` (or whatever this may be called in an english Word). I think, this might be a cause but I'm giving up now, waiting for the brave guy that understands what's going on.

---

**EDIT 4:**
Answering questions asked by Arjan in his comments:

1. In Word, the whole line is clickable
2. The dots are visible in the PDF. They are defined to be the filling mark between the heading title and the page number
3. Yes, the dots are clickable in the PDF.
4. The relevant hyperlink covers the whole line from beginning of chapter title until the end of the line number
5. If I change the numbering of my chapters from using tabs between number and text to spaces between number and text, the hyperlink in the TOC changes: it now covers all the line from start of chapter number until end of page number. But there's still such a hyperlink fragment **after** the TOC entry.
6. When I copy the line from PDF, the dots are just dots.

Comment: As an aside: if this a regular thing you need to do, then surely you can change the formatting of URLs in Word?

Comment: @Arjan: I tried that but couldn't get it to work. The advantage of formatting the hyperlinks directly in PDF is, that they are not present when you print the document. That way, you get an accessible screen version and a non-disturbing print version.

Comment: No matter what (main) style: things could always be a hyperlink. I'd *guess* one wants the whole line to be clickable, so "convert Word styles to hyperlinks" should probably be enabled. In Word: 1) Are the red parts clickable too? In the PDF: 2) Are the dots (the 2nd red part) visible? 3) Are the dots clickable? 4) Are the dots part of the same hyperlink as the heading text and the page number? If all yes: then what if you change your TOC to use spaces between the heading number and header text? (Just for a test; it won't look well with spaces.)

Comment: As for font size: indeed the "Tabs" (or whatever they are) are taller in your first screen capture. Then, to get the right clickable region, I guess Adobe has no other choice than to start a new hyperlink? 5) Are the dots taller too?

Comment: One more thing, if you copy a line from the PDF: 6) Are the dots a Tab?

Comment: @Arjan: see edited post.

Comment: just a small tip but I use pdf24 to print pdf directly from my word documents which works perfectly well maybe you'll give it a try

Comment: The pilcrow (¶) holds the paragraph formatting in Word, like paragraph spacing. It can often surprise you: if you have a list and make the pilcrow red and italic, then the list bullet or number will become red italic too. One cannot select that bullet or number itself to remove that formatting, but when selecting the pilcrow then one can change it. Odd. (At least, this was how old version of Word worked.)

Comment: Your answer for 5) refers to the PDF, right? (Not to the green and red in your image about the Word styles.) Are the font size for the two styles indeed different? (In Edit 2 you wrote about making things smaller, but maybe it's sufficient to make the sizes equal?)

Comment: @Arjan: regarding the pilcrow comment, I knew that, but since I always generate a new TOC, I have no influence on that. Your assumption in the other comment is right. This is becoming too confusing for me since it seems like the heading styles are relevant for the behavior too...

Comment: So what about the font sizes: doesn't choosing equal sizes (maybe even the same font) solve the issue? (If with "since I always generate a new TOC" you're saying that changes in the styles are not preserved, then you're doing something odd there. "Update fields" should not remove your own styling. But that's not related to this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me is to change the formatting of headings (not of the TOC elements): When I change the character after the chapter number from <kbd>TAB</kbd> to `SPACE`, the generated TOC is as I expected it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that every line has a single hyperlink, covering the number, Tab character and its title. Next, in the PDF, this is split up in three parts, due to the absolute positioning of the text in the PDF. I'm quite sure you'll get a Tab character when copying that second hyperlink.